# ORMLIte[ServiceStack] . SaveReference method does not add items in the List

Tags: c#, orm, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have following code that I am doing for my ORMLite Demo:

```
[Alias("ProUser")]
public class DomainUser : IProUser
{
    public int UserType { get; set; }
    public string Id{ get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public UserType UserTypeEnum
    {
        get { return (UserType)UserType; }
        set { UserType = (int)value; }
    }
}

public class Order
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ProUserId { get; set; }

    public string Details { get; set; }

}
```

1. Now, as you can notice there is a referential relationship between DomainUser and Order with List Orders property.
2. I can call Db.SaveReferences(user, user.Orders) and see that if I have changed any thing inside the domain then it worked very well.
3. However, IF I add a new item in the list ORMLite does not save this.

My test below demonstrates this probem very well

```
DomainUser user = repository.Find("Someone.Else") as DomainUser;
user.UserTypeEnum = UserType.Domain;
user.HomeAddress.StreetName = "Some new street";
user.Orders[1].Details = "Nestle Chocolates";
user.Orders.Add(new Order
{
    Details = "Reese",
    ProUserId = user.Id
});

// This one would be OK since the user already has two orders in the DB
Assert.AreEqual(2, user.Orders.Count);  
repository.Update(user);


DomainUser retval =  repository.Find(user.Id) as DomainUser;

// However, this one would fail because no new order has been added.
Assert.AreEqual(3, user.Orders.Count);
```

The confusing thing is that I saw that ORMLite is trying to add a new record because I see an insert query being executed. I am not sure why DB is not reflecting it though....

Here is how Repository looks like for Find() and Update() methods:

```
public IProUser Find(string id)
        {
            DomainUser user = Db.LoadSingleById<DomainUser>(id);
            return user;
        }

 public IProUser Update(DomainUser user)
        {
            using(Db.OpenTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
            { 
                Db.Save(user);
                Db.SaveReferences(user,user.HomeAddress);
                Db.SaveReferences(user,user.Orders);

                return Find(user.Id);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide the implementations of repository `Find()` and `Update()`, as it's not clear what OrmLite API's you're using in these methods.

Comment: I am sorry for missing out on those details. I updated the original question with the implementations

Comment: I also added the fact that I am using an alias called "ProUser" for Domainuser.

Comment: I've been unable to repro this issue [added in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/275bf3a1f4fade5257e0dfde0a47e543eec23ff6). What version of OrmLite are you using?

Comment: Actually just noticed you're not committing your transactions, I've updated the commit to [show usage within a transaction](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/d40974c5297e44323ede8e52c2728fdf94ee6cfb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly commit your ADO.NET transaction, i.e:

```
using(var trans = Db.OpenTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
{ 
    Db.Save(user);
    Db.SaveReferences(user,user.HomeAddress);
    Db.SaveReferences(user,user.Orders);

    trans.Commit();

    return Find(user.Id);
}
```